Electromagnet/Solenoid affect on other hardware
I plan on using an electromagnet or a solenoid to attach a brace to a robot. These would be either two of the 5V Electromagnet - 25 Kg Holding Force electromagnets or two LEDEX B4HD-254-M-36 solenoids. The electromagnet/solenoid would not be on the brace but on the robot. The brace has some sensors and microcontrollers on board. I had a few questions:

If I had sensors like the BNO055 IMU sensor also on the brace, would it be affected by a solenoid or the Adafruit electromagnet? Is there a distance it has to be from the electromagnet/solenoid?
Would that affect small microcontrollers like the Seeed XIAO ESP32C3? All of my electronics will be enclosed in a petg plastic case, but not sure if that matters.
Would it be better to use a solenoid or an electromagnet when considering having other electronics


In general the electronics is quite resilient to static and low frequency magnetic current.
My experience with EMC testing of complex devices that use sensitive RF measuring inputs and high speed data lines (of also switching power supplies etc) there is rarely if ever an issue on so called "magnetic fields" immunity test, where they put huge coil over the DUT and induce magnetic fields in up to kHz range (depends on EMC standard used). This makes sense, since usually apart from inductors, most devices are not operating on a principle of magnetic fields or are not sensitive to magnetic fields. Also, electronics usually does not include a lot of ferromagnetic material, where fields would get stronger. I assume it would be very different if one would be testing magnetic sensors or anything that has big coils or ferromagnetic components.
Issues might occur during switching zero current to high current and vice versa. During this time huge change in magnetic fields occurs. This might induce current and cause problems. Again, usually due to lac of ferromagnetics in the circuits this not a problem.
Hence i would not worry about EPS and supporting electronics.
BNO055 IMU could be affected as it is using magnetic gyros, although i think complex sensors like this usually filter out the background one way or another.
Still, there is no way of knowing before trying i think, like in a lot if EMC problems. Since this is EMC/EMI problem, you can diminish the chances of issues by following best practices. Since we are talking about magnetic, not "RF" field*, you need to identify coils in your setup, not just obvious ones, but also any coils that you created by mistake, like wireing and pcb traces.. the distance between the coils  will play a big role, put things far apart. Even more importantly, make sure axis of sensors and pcbs are perpendicular to axis of disturbance coils. For example, axis perpendicular to face of the pcb has to be perpendicular to axis of the disturbance coul etc
Moreover, wireing should be done in a way to avoid loops. Bring + and - wires close together if possible intertwined. Take spexial care you don't create loops with ground or - wires, e.g. bringing power supply cable to both sensor and pcb, and then connecting sensor and pcb with another cable on a different side of setup creating a huge area loop with wires. The connection between sensor and electronics in the said case has to go back from sensor to power supply and the to electronics, to minimize the loop area created by wires and cables. Bear in mind this is just an example.
*by RF i mean far field, the radiative electromagnetic field, and by magnetic field i mean magnetic part of near field

Your BNO055's magnetometer may pick up the solenoids when in use depending on how close the are. You will have to test this to know for sure. You can use shielded coils if this will be a problem.
